# Java:Задача про счастливый билет. Как лучше синхронизировать потоки?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Ставить synchronized на весь while нельзя,так как потоки просто друг за другом выполнятся и все. Нужно каким-то образом  синхронизировать внутри while, но как?

```
static int x = 0;
static int count = 0;

static class LuckyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (x < 999999) {
            x++;
            if ((x % 10) + (x / 10) % 10 + (x / 100) % 10 == (x / 1000)
                    % 10 + (x / 10000) % 10 + (x / 100000) % 10) {
                System.out.println(x);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что именно хочется синхронизировать?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то Вы запускаете n потоков и каждый должен считать сумму цифр 6-значных чисел. Делается это при помощи класса `AtomicInteger`

```java
static AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger(0);
static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

static class LuckyThread extends Thread {
  private int sum(int val) {
    int res = 0;
    while (val > 0) {
      res += val % 10;
      val /= 10;
    }
    return res;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    int val = x.incrementAndGet();
    while (val < 999999) {
      if (sum(val % 1000) == sum(val / 1000)) {
        System.out.println(val);
        count.incrementAndGet();
      }
      val = x.incrementAndGet();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: В методе `sum()` условие цикла лучше сделать `val > 0` - а то с нулем выполняется лишний проход, который ничего не меняет

Comment: @m.vokhm Вы правы. Что-то я не о том думал. Поправил

Answer (score 1):

У вас задача прекрасно параллелится, и тут не нужно использовать никакую синхронизацию. Прямо совсем.

Разбиваем данный диапазон `(0 ... 1000000)` на `N` диапазонов, и каждый диапазон обсчитываем в отдельном потоке. А `N` - это число потоков.

```
public static int parallelSearch(int threadCount) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
    Collection<Future<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>(threadCount);

    int limit = 1_000_000;
    int step = limit / threadCount;
    int x = 0;
    while (x < limit) {
        int finalX = x;
        futures.add(threadPool.submit(() -> search(finalX, finalX + step)));
        x += step;
    }

    int result = 0;
    for (Future<Integer> future : futures)
        result += future.get();

    return result;
}

private static int search(int x, int limit) {
    int count = 0;
    while (x <= limit) {
        x++;
        if ((x % 10) + (x / 10) % 10 + (x / 100) % 10 == (x / 1000)
                % 10 + (x / 10000) % 10 + (x / 100000) % 10) {
            System.out.println(x);
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```